# Boolean Recursive Method To Check Diagonal Spots on a Board

Tags: java, recursion

I am doing the Queens Challenge and I already have a method to iteratively check the rows and columns.  I am trying to recursively check all of the diagonal spots, beginning at the current queen location.

```
//pre: r & c within bounds of board
//post: returns true if no queens are diagonally challenging
public boolean diaCheck(int r, int c){
    if(r >= 0 && r < board.length && c >= 0 && c < board.length){  //base case: r or 
        if(board[r][c]==1){ //base case: the spot being checked is a queen
            return false;
        }else{ //recursive case 
            return diaCheck(r-1, c-1) && 
                diaCheck(r-1, c+1) && 
                diaCheck(r+1, c-1) && 
                diaCheck(r+1, c+1));     
    } 
    return true;

}
```

I tried this and I was expecting it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic idea is completely right. The problem with your code is, that you don't check only the diagonals of the current queen location. Instead your code checks the diagonals for each field on the diagonal and so on. So your code will always return false if there is any other queen on the chess field.

Moreover the code directly returns false as your "base case" is always fulfilled as this is the current location of your queen. Take care that you just check the diagonals from the current queen location.

The solution might be something like the following. The code below is not tested.

```
// Entry point of recursion. Starts a recursion for each diagonal.
// We don't want to check current queens location as this would always return false.
public boolean diaCheck(int r, int c){
    return diaCheck(r-1, c-1, -1, -1) && 
       diaCheck(r-1, c+1, -1, +1) && 
       diaCheck(r+1, c-1, +1, -1) && 
       diaCheck(r+1, c+1, +1, +1));     
}

// Method to check a single diagonal direction for a queen
public boolean diaCheck(int r, int c, int incVertical, int incHorizontal){
    if(r >= 0 && r < board.length && c >= 0 && c < board.length){  //base case: r or 
        if(board[r][c]==1){
            return false;
        }else{ 
            return diaCheck(r + incVertical,c + incHorizontal, incVertical, incHorizontal);
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```